# PoshRsJob Performance Issue

Tags: multithreading, performance, powershell

Why is using Multithreading in PowerShell so unbelievable slow. Am I doing anything wrong? I am using the PoshRsJob Module.

RSJobs:

```
(Measure-Command {

    $output = Start-RSJob -InputObject $shortDump -ScriptBlock {
        Param($out, $shortDump)

        $retObj = [pscustomobject]@{
            UserMail = $_.Mail
            Type = $_.Type
        }
       # return $retObj
       $retObj

    } | Wait-RSJob

    $out.Add( $( Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob) )
    # $out += $( Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob )

}).TotalSeconds
```

and

Standard `foreach`:

```
(Measure-Command {

    foreach ($obj in $shortDump) {

        $retObj = [pscustomobject]@{
            UserMail =$obj.Mail
            Type = $obj.Type
        }
        # $out+= $retObj
        $out.Add($retObj)
    }
}).TotalSeconds
```

My goal is to build objects faster, because i have ~ 300.000 objects to build.

edit: Here is a another example. It's totally slow!

## fast

```
$out = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
"default"
(Measure-Command {

    for ($x = 0; $x -lt 100000; $x++) 
    {

        $retObj = [pscustomobject]@{
            UserMail = 'test'
            Type =  'test2'
            Test = 'default'
        }
        $out.Add($retObj)
    }

}).TotalSeconds
$out2 = $out
```

## horribly slow

```
$out = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Test = `"RSJobs"`
"RSJobs"

$ScriptBlock = {     

[pscustomobject]@{
    UserMail = 'test'
    Type =  'test2'
    Test = $Using:Test
}
}

(Measure-Command {
    1..100000 | Start-RSJob -Name {$_} -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock   
    $out.Add( $( Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob) )

}).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: How big is the input size in your test? Also, maybe include the `TotalSeconds` result for reference

Comment: Input size is a array with 10.000 objects. The difference is: 
RSJobs:
106,0617351 seconds
standard foreach:
0,3592102 seconds

Comment: Looks like the RSJobs code is incomplete (not all variables are accounted for, etc.). Can you provided a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In the meantime, I notice that the blog for PostRsJobs emphasises that you should *not* put `Start-RSJob` in a foreach loop, else you'll have the overhead of assembling new runspace pools for each item in the loop.

Comment: Where did I put Start-RsJob in a foreach loop?

Comment: PowerShell Version: 5.1
PoshRsJob Version: 1.7.3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new runspace has overhead. So with many small jobs then you are adding the overhead every single time.

```
(measure-command {[pscustomobject]@{'a'='b'}}).totalmilliseconds
0.1773

{start-rsjob -scriptblock {[pscustomobject]@{'a'='b'}}}).totalmilliseconds
93.0173
```

Then you are adding even more overhead retrieving all of the returned data from the individual jobs into one object, which was basically your goal in the first place.

Basically, build 1 object from 100,000 objects vs create a runspace 100,000 times each creating 1 object then return all of these objects to build 1 object from 100,000 objects.

I don't see how you are going to get any gain in efficiency using runspaces in this application. If there was an expensive calculation to determine each object, and then you made just a few runspaces and ran a subset of your array in each, maybe.

Comment: " If there was an expensive calculation to determine each object, and then you made just a few runspaces and ran a subset of your array in each, maybe."
I understand. Yes there must a lot of conditions be true, before a new object is created. I will check this out. Thank you

(measure-command {start-rsjob -scriptblock {[pscustomobject]@{'a'='b'}}}).totalmilliseconds

Last question: Is there any other solution to create objects faster in powershell without using jobs or runspaces.

Comment: @CaspervanDoorn Runspaces is the lowest overhead method of parallelization that I know of. There is also Workflows, but again I don't think parallelization is the magic bullet for you.... Runspaces isn't object creation though, `[pscustomobject]` is the most efficient vs `New-Object` or `Select-Object`.